# Can this be made quicker to enter formula and date?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have this code below that goes through each sheet in a workbook enters the range of date and a formula, however currently the code is take quiet a long time to get it done. how can I improve this?
Thank you

```
 For i = 1 To 9
        Dim Lastrow As Long
        Lastrow = Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(i).Cells(Worksheets(i).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            d = FirstDate
   
            Do Until d > LastDate
            Dim formulaline As String, formulaline2 As String, formulaline3 As String
            formulaline = "=" & Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(i).Range("AA2").Text
            formulaline2 = Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(i).Range("AA3").Text & "["
            formulaline3 = monthandyear & Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(i).Range("AA5").Text
            
            Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(i).Cells(Lastrow, "A").Value = d
            Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(i).Cells(Lastrow, "C").Value = formulaline & formulaline2 & formulaline3
            Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
            d = d + 1
            Loop
        
        Next
```

Comment: Do cells AA2, AA3 and AA5 have formulas in them ? Why are the formulaline assignments repeated for every d inside the Do Loop, do they change ?

Comment: technically only AA3 is different for each sheet. They do not contain a formula. it is text that makes up the vlookup formula

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'"this line changes for each sheet" C:\Users\axela\Desktop\STORES - Copy\STORES - Copy\BONHAM (I&H)\[ month and year here, ]DAILY'!$A$3:$I$50,9,FALSE),"")

Comment: For each adjacent d in column A i would like to put the formula in column c. So if d is from column A40 to A70 I would like the formula to go in the adjacent in Column C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding formulas below existing data/formulas?

If you are you might not need to loop.

This might work but will probably need adjusted to put the dates in column A.

```
Dim formulaline As String, formulaline2 As String, formulaline3 As String
Dim Lastrow As Long
    For I = 1 To 9

        Lastrow = Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(I).Cells(Worksheets(I).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        d = LastDate - FirstDate ' get no of dates, i.e. rows, the formula needs to go in

        formulaline = "=" & Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(I).Range("AA2").Text
        formulaline2 = Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(I).Range("AA3").Text & "["
        formulaline3 = monthandyear & Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(I).Range("AA5").Text

        Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(I).Cells(Lastrow, "A").Value = FirstDate
        Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls").Worksheets(I).Cells(Lastrow, "C").Resize(d).Value = formulaline & formulaline2 & formulaline3


    Next I
```

Comment: thank you, but this is only entering the first day of the month not the whole month

Answer (score 1):

**It looks like you could optimize:**

- Turn off screen updating
- Turn off automatic calculations
- Disable events
- Use `With` statement

```
  'turn off unnecessary applications
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  For i = 1 To 9

        Dim Lastrow As Long
        
        With Workbooks("MAIN CASH DRAWER.xls")
        
             Lastrow = .Worksheets(i).Cells(Worksheets(i).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
             d = FirstDate
        
             Do Until d > LastDate
             
                 Dim formulaline As String, formulaline2 As String, formulaline3 As String
                
                 formulaline = "=" & .Worksheets(i).Range("AA2").Text
                 formulaline2 = .Worksheets(i).Range("AA3").Text & "["
                 formulaline3 = monthandyear & .Worksheets(i).Range("AA5").Text
                 
                 .Worksheets(i).Cells(Lastrow, "A").Value = d
                 .Worksheets(i).Cells(Lastrow, "C").Value = formulaline & formulaline2 & formulaline3

                 Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
                 d = d + 1
                 
             Loop
        End With
Next

'turn on applications
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

For more information: https://analysistabs.com/vba/optimize-code-run-macros-faster/

**Note:** If you have a problem running the macro and it debugs because of an error, Excel could start working weird, due to disabling applications without turning them on again. In that case you can run the following macro just to turn applications back on:

```
Sub turn_applications_on()

   'turn on applications
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Or you can just restart Excel.

Comment: It works well but now excel formula wont add or show result until i press save, can you help?

Comment: Never mind, I rechecked automatic in options.

Comment: @MohamadBallout I'm glad it helped.